# Kubuntu 22.04 dual monitor black

Tags: kubuntu

Running Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, have a AMD Radeon RX6700XT graphic cards and my primary monitor goes black right after logging in. I have installed the AMD drivers from their website, still the same problem. How could I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had to enable the monitor in display settings lol